# Slideshow of photographs automatically uploaded to Google+?

Tags: google-plus, images

How can I view a slideshow of the photographs that have been automatically uploaded to Google+ from my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to [picasaweb.google.com](https://picasaweb.google.com) you'll find an album that is called `Instant Uploads`. Enter and click on the `Slideshow` button on the top left.